# STDERR redirection to STDOUT lost if backticks can't exec

Tags: linux, perl

I’m finding `STDERR` redirection within a backticks call can be lost if the command fails to execute.  I’m stumped by the behavior I am seeing.

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`DNE`; print $out'  
Can't exec "DNE": No such file or directory at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1.

$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`DNE 2>&1`; print $out'
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1.

$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`echo 123; DNE 2>&1`; print $out'
123
sh: DNE: command not found
```

Is my syntax incorrect?

I'm using Perl 5.8.5 on Linux.

Comment: I reviewed this documentation prior to submitting this question.  I'm still stumped.  I believe my syntax matches the following:
To capture a command's STDERR and STDOUT together:
$output = `cmd 2>&1`;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, but in one case `perl` is dropping the error message.

In general, consider testing during initialization that your system has the command you want, and fail early if it is missing.

```
my $foopath = "/usr/bin/foo";
die "$0: $foopath is not executable" unless -x $foopath;

# later ...

my $output = `$foopath 2>&1`;
die "$0: $foopath exited $?" if $?;
```

To fully understand the differences in output, it is necessary to understand details of Unix system programming. Read on.

### Unix file descriptors

Consider a simple `perl` invocation.

```
perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"'
```

Its output is

```
hi
bye
```

Note that the output of `print` goes to `STDOUT`, the standard output, and `warn` writes to `STDERR`, the standard error. When run from a terminal, both appear on the terminal, but we can send them to different places. For example

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' >/dev/null
bye
```

The null device or `/dev/null` discards any output sent to it, and so in the command above, “hi” disappears. The command above is shorthand for

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' 1>/dev/null
bye
```

That is, 1 is the file descriptor for `STDOUT`. To throw away “bye” instead, run

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' 2>/dev/null
hi
```

As you can see, 2 is the file descriptor for `STDERR`. (For completeness, the file descriptor for `STDIN` is 0.)

In the Bourne shell and its derivatives, we can also merge `STDOUT` and `STDERR` with `2>&1`. Read it as “make file descriptor 2’s output go to the same place as file descriptor 1’s.”

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' 2>&1
hi
bye
```

Terminal output does not highlight the distinction, but an extra redirection shows what’s happening. We can discard both by running

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Order matters with this family of shells that processes redirections in left-to-right order, so transposing the two yields

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' 2>&1 >/dev/null
bye
```

This may be surprising at first. The shell first processes `2>&1` which means send `STDERR` to the same destination as `STDOUT`—which it already is: the terminal! Then it processes `>/dev/null` and redirects `STDOUT` to the null device.

This duplication of file descriptors happens by calling [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html), which is usually a wrapper for [`fcntl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html).

### Redirection and pipelines

Now say we want to add a prefix to each line of the output of our command.

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' | sed -e 's/^/got: /'
bye
got: hi
```

The order is different, but remember that `STDERR` and `STDOUT` are different streams. Notice also that only “hi” got a prefix. To get both lines, they both have to appear on `STDOUT`.

```
$ perl -e 'print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"' 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/got: /'
got: bye
got: hi
```

To construct a pipeline, the shell creates child processes with `fork`, performs redirections with `dup2`, and starts each stage of the pipeline with calls to `exec` in the appropriate processes. For the pipeline above, the process is similar to

- shell: `fork` a process to run `sed`
- shell: wait for exit status from `sed` with `waitpid`

  - sed: create a `pipe` to feed input to `perl`
  - sed: `fork` a process to run `perl`
  - sed: `dup2` to make `STDIN` read from the read end of the pipe
  - sed: `exec` the `sed` command
  - sed: wait for input on `STDIN`

    - perl: `dup2` to send `STDOUT` to the write end of the pipe from step 3
    - perl: `dup2` to send `STDERR` to `STDOUT`’s destination
    - perl: `exec` the `perl` command
    - perl: write output and eventually `exit`
  - sed: receive and edit the input stream
  - sed: detect end-of-file on pipe
  - sed: reap `perl`’s exit status with `waitpid`
  - sed: `exit`
- shell: populate `$?` with the return value from `waitpid`

Note that the child processes are created in right-to-left order. This is because shells in the Bourne family define the exit status of a pipeline to be the exit status of the last process.

### Do-It-Yourself Pipelines

You can build the above pipeline in Perl with the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = open my $fh, "-|";
die "$0: fork: $!" unless defined $pid;

if ($pid) {
  while (<$fh>) {
    s/^/got: /;
    print;
  }
}
else {
  open STDERR, ">&=", \*STDOUT or print "$0: dup: $!";
  exec "perl", "-e", q[print "hi\n"; warn "bye\n"]
    or die "$0: exec: $!";
}
```

The first call to `open` does a lot of work for us, as noted in the [perlfunc documentation on `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> For three or more arguments if MODE is `"|-"`, the filename is interpreted as a command to which output is to be piped, and if MODE is `"-|"`, the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us. In the two-argument (and one-argument) form, one should replace dash (`"-"`) with the command. See [Using `open` for IPC in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC) for more examples of this.

Its output is

```
$ ./simple-pipeline
got: bye
got: hi
```

The code above hardcodes the duplication of `STDOUT`, which we can see below.

```
$ ./simple-pipeline >/dev/null
```

### Perl backticks

To capture the output of another command, `perl` sets up the same machinery, which you can see in [`pp_backtick`](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/fc99edcf6b3d3de59f7bdefc42a09167fd8b96f5/pp_sys.c#L296) (in `pp_sys.c`), which calls [`Perl_my_popen`](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/5d1d68e202770f3a59cef999bc11d534a2364d5f/util.c#L2625) (in `util.c`) to create a child process and set up the plumbing (`fork`, `pipe`, `dup2`). The child does some plumbing and calls `Perl_do_exec3` (in `doio.c`) to start the command whose output we want. There we notice [a relevant comment](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/0eb30aebe20a48d634d4e484bc9e6005dffc1420/doio.c#L1514):

```
/* handle the 2>&1 construct at the end */
```

The implementation recognizes the sequence `2>&1`, duplicates `STDOUT`, and removes the redirection from the command to be passed to the shell.

```
if (*s == '>' && s[1] == '&' && s[2] == '1'
    && s > cmd + 1 && s[-1] == '2' && isSPACE(s[-2])
    && (!s[3] || isSPACE(s[3])))
{
    const char *t = s + 3;

    while (*t && isSPACE(*t))
        ++t;
    if (!*t && (PerlLIO_dup2(1,2) != -1)) {
        s[-2] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

Later we see

```
PerlProc_execl(PL_sh_path, "sh", "-c", cmd, (char *)NULL);
PERL_FPU_POST_EXEC
S_exec_failed(aTHX_ PL_sh_path, fd, do_report);
```

Inside `S_exec_failed`, we find

```
if (ckWARN(WARN_EXEC))
    Perl_warner(aTHX_ packWARN(WARN_EXEC), "Can't exec \"%s\": %s",
                cmd, Strerror(e));
```

That is one of the warnings you asked about in your question.

### Timelines

Let’s walk through the details of how `perl` processes the commands from your question.

#### As expected

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`DNE`; print $out'
Can't exec "DNE": No such file or directory at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1.
```

No surprises here.

A subtle detail is important to understand. The code above that handles `2>&1` in-house runs only when a condition is true of the command to be executed:

```
if (*s != ' ' && !isALPHA(*s) &&
    strchr("$&*(){}[]'\";\\|?<>~`\n",*s)) {
```

This is an optimization. If the command in backticks contains the above shell metacharacters, then `perl` has to hand it off to the shell. *But* if no shell metacharacters are present, `perl` can `exec` the command directly—saving the `fork` and shell startup costs.

The non-existent command `DNE` contains no shell metacharacters, so `perl` does all the work. The exec-category warning is generated because the command failed and you enabled the `warnings` pragma. The perlop documentation tells us that backticks or `qx//` returns `undef` in scalar context when the command fails, so that’s why you get the warning about printing the undefined value of `$out`.

#### Missing warning

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`DNE 2>&1`; print $out'
Use of uninitialized value in print at -e line 1.
```

Where did the failed `exec` warning go?

Remember the basic steps of creating a child process that runs another command:

1. Create a pipe for the child to send its output to the parent.
2. Call `fork` to create a nearly identical child process.
3. In the child, `dup2` to connect `STDOUT` to the write end of the pipe.
4. In the child, `exec` to cause the newly created child to execute another program instead.
5. In the parent, read the contents of the pipe.

To capture the output of another command, `perl` goes through these steps. In preparation to attempt running `DNE 2>&1`, `perl` forks a child and *in the child process* causes `STDERR` to be a duplicate of the `STDOUT`, but there is another side effect.

```
if (!*t && (PerlLIO_dup2(1,2) != -1)) {
    s[-2] = '\0';
    break;
}
```

If `2>&1` is at the end of the command and the `dup2` succeeds, then `perl` writes a NUL byte just before the redirection. This has the effect of removing it from the command, *e.g.*, `DNE 2>&1` becomes `DNE`! Now, with no shell metacharacters in the command, `perl` *in the child process* thinks to itself, ‘Self, we can `exec` this command directly.’

The call to `exec` fails because `DNE` does not exist. The child still emits the failed `exec` warning on `STDERR`. It doesn’t go to the terminal because of the `dup2` that pointed `STDERR` to the same place as `STDOUT`: the write end of the pipe back to the parent.

The parent process detects that the child exited abnormally, and ignores the contents of the pipe because the result of failed command-execution is documented to be `undef`.

#### Different warning

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $out=`echo 123; DNE 2>&1`; print $out'
123
sh: DNE: command not found
```

Here we see a different diagnostic of `DNE` not existing. The first shell metacharacter encountered is `;`, so `perl` hands the command unchanged to the shell for execution. The `echo` completes normally, and then `DNE` fails *in the shell*, and the shell’s `STDOUT` and `STDERR` go back to the parent process. From `perl`’s perspective, the shell executed fine, so there is nothing to warn about.

### Related note

When you enable the `warnings` pragma—a **Very** Good Practice!—this enables the `exec` warning category. To see the full list of these warnings, search the [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) documentation for the string `W exec`.

Observe the difference.

```
$ perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -e 'my $out=`DNE`; print $out'
Can't exec "DNE": No such file or directory at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $out in print at -e line 1.

$ perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -M-warnings=exec -e 'my $out=`DNE`; print $out'
Use of uninitialized value $out in print at -e line 1.
```

The latter invocation is equivalent to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'exec';

my $out = `DNE`;
print defined($out) ? $out : "command failed\n";
```

I like formatting my own error messages when something goes wrong with an `exec`, pipe `open`, and so on. This means I usually disable exec warnings, but it also means I have to be extra-careful to test return values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Greg.  I originally noticed the 'cant exec' message is lost if STDERR is redirected. It makes sense that perl is generating the line.  It still seems odd that it gets suppressed (and subsequently lost) if redirection is included within the backticks call

Comment: In the **Redirection and pipelines** you wrote `sed: fork a process to run perl`, but when I run `perl -e 'sleep 333'|grep 'sdfsfsd'` on my ubuntu I see  that `perl`'s father is `bash` but not `grep`. Why?

Answer (score 8):

The problem in here is that redirections are done by shell. And your `...` command is not run via shell - Perl tries to find DNE program using $PATH, and it fails.

If you need to capture both stdout and stderr, you can go multiple ways, but the safest in my opinion is to use [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm), or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm).

If you're feeling adventureous, you can try doing things like this, but please rember that it's bad idea:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $o=`sh -c "DNE 2>&1"`; print $o' 
sh: 1: DNE: not found
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments depesz.  O

Comment: My scripts will be executed on numerous machines and I don't have the means to facilitate package mgmt on all the machines.  Because of this, I've kept my distance from third party libraries.  IPC::Open3 can be sourced on the majority of my machines which should open the door to easier development for me.  Thanks for the help and guidance.

Comment: @jgrump2012: note that IPC::Open3 is a core module, i.e. it's  included in Perl distributions - http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-I.html

Answer (score 2):

```
  my $op =`dne 2>&1;`;
```

This works. Notice the semicolon `;` at the end of redirection.

Or you can use below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $op=`dne 2>&1 1>output.txt`;

print $op;
```

Output:

```
sh: dne: command not found
```

Though, why exactly STDOUT is not printed in case of `dne 2>&1` is still unknown to me.

But when you use redirection of STDOUT to a file, the output is printed. It's weird, But works.